# Translated menu items with menu_build_tree in drupal 7

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I'm having an issue with menu item translations with custom rendering of menu tree.

I see all languages displayed at the same time whenever I change the current language. Items have translation set it works if I enable the built-in main menu block but not with my code.

I've tried adding 't($string)' and set 'language' in params; but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here ?

I have the following code in template.php for my theme :

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    $params = array('max_depth' => 3, 'language' => 'fr');
    $menu = menu_build_tree('main-menu', $params);
    $main_menu_tree = menu_build_tree('main-menu', $params);
    $html = '<ul id="dropdown-menu" class="fixed">';

    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)))
        $nodeid = arg(1);

    foreach ($main_menu_tree as $item_menu) {//for each main element
        $isSecondLevel = isset($item_menu['below']) && !empty($item_menu['below']);
        $active = '';
        if ($item_menu['link']['link_path'] == 'node/' . $nodeid) { $active = 'active';
        }
        if ($isSecondLevel) {
            $html .= '<li>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<li>';
        }

        $html .= '<a class="' . $active . '" href="' . url($item_menu['link']['link_path']) . '">';
        $html .= $item_menu['link']['link_title'];
        $html .= '</a>';

        //is there any sub elements to display
        if ($isSecondLevel) {
            $html .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';

            foreach ($item_menu['below'] as $item_submenu) {//for each sub element
                $isThirdLevel = isset($item_submenu['below']) && !empty($item_submenu['below']) ? 'main-menu-third_level' : '';

                $html .= '<li>';
                $html .= '<a href="' . url($item_submenu['link']['link_path']) . '">';

                $html .= t($item_submenu['link']['link_title']);

                $html .= '</a>';
                $html .= '</li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    $variables['main_menu_html'] = $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normaly I use [`i18n_menu_translated_tree`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/i18n_menu_translated_tree/7) function. For example:

```
$main_menu_tree = i18n_menu_translated_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
```